# How can I make an array to insert a bunch of strings?

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple obfuscator in c# forms and I'm using this code to insert it:

```
string a = RandomString(8);
string b = RandomString(8);
string c = RandomString(8);
string d = RandomString(8);
etc...

Code.Text = Code.Text.Insert(0, "set " + a + "=a\n" + "set " + b + "=b\n" + "set " + c + "=c\n" + "set " + d + "=d\n" etc...);
```

This is the output:

```
set pbatbpkz=a
set aqtwbqlg=b
set hitsvkvc=c
set imuwqdfy=d
etc...
```

I need to keep the random strings separate so that I can later insert code to replace characters like "a" with string a.

This obviously does not look efficient or professional. I'm considerably new to c#, so I don't know how I could make something like an array to insert this block of text.

## Solved by Jawad

---

Here's the slightly better code:

```
Dictionary<char, string> strDict = new Dictionary<char, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    if (!strDict.ContainsKey((char)(i + 97)))
    {
        strDict.Add((char)(i + 97), RandomString(8));
    }
    else
    {
        strDict[(char)(i + 97)] = RandomString(8);
    }
}

string letterTable = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
StringBuilder obfuscationTable = new StringBuilder("");

foreach (char c in letterTable)
{
    obfuscationTable.AppendLine("set " + c + "=" + strDict[c]);
}

Code.Text = Code.Text.Insert(0, obfuscationTable.ToString());
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't understand what you need. Do you wanna know how to build an Array with the same values as a..z variables?

Comment: I mean something such as: for ever character in "abcd etc..." insert "set " + chosenLetter + "=chosenLetter\n". That way I wouldn't have to type down a massive string to insert. However, I'm fairly new to c# as I said, so I don't know how to make an array to pick and use those letters and insert them.

Comment: one thing to be aware of, not that you show the code for RandomString, but if it is just a random string, then it is possible to generate the same string for two different letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a Dictionary.

```
   Dictionary<char, string> strDict = new Dictionary<char, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            if(!strDict.ContainsKey((char)(i+97)))
            {
                strDict.Add((char)(i + 97), RandomString());
            }
            else
            {
                strDict[(char)(i + 97)] = RandomString();
            }
        }
```

This will fill your strDict with random strings that can be accessed with characters from 'a' to 'z'
Then you get these strings by:

```
string strA = strDict['a'] //and so on
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll add the code resulting from this in the question!

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure you are looking for is a [`Dictionary<char, string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Naively you would use it like this:

```
var charLookup = new Dictionary<char, string>{
    {'a', RandomString(8)},
    ...
    {'z', RandomString(8)},
};

Code.Text = Code.Text.Insert(0, "set " + charLookup['a'] + "=a\n" ....
```

There are many ways to write this in less code. I would recommend using a loop to populate your dictionary, and linq to generate your string.

You should be able to do this in 3 lines of code.

Alternately use a seeded random number generator to do this in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary that maps these characters to random strings.

```
Dictionary<string, string> RandomStringDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
RandomStringDictionary.Add("a", RandomString(8));
...
RandomStringDictionary.Add("z", RandomString(8));
```

Then iterate over your text, and for each character do

```
RandomStringDictionary[CurrentCharacter]
```